# Creating a Naka Rushton filter for images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to computer vision, and looking at implementing a Naka Rushton filter for contrast enhancement (in Matlab). I tried a simple system where I just use the image as the set of contrasts, and apply the filter equation directly, but it did not work. Here is what I tried:

```
    img=imread('image.png');
    w=5; %guess parameter from literature for my images
    Ic=multithresh(img); % to find Otsu's thresholding parameter
    NR_img=(img.^w)./(Ic^w+img.^w); %The NR equation
    imshow(NR_img);
```

This does not work (perhaps obviously). I am looking at books on vision, and all of them just mention the equation for the filter, and not much about implementing it for images. Would someone be able to direct me to resources, or help me get started on a simple filter for this?

Comment: Is your image grayscale?

Comment: No it is not, should I start with a grayscale image?

Comment: would this be what you are looking for: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/beta/Psychtoolbox/Psychometric/ComputeNakaRushton.m ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think my problem arises due to finding the sigma parameter (which is the threshold), which they just pass as input.